# wpf binding text to parent listbox's contents

Tags: wpf, vb.net, xaml, binding, ancestor

I have a listBox whose items are to be shown in a textbox format, like so:-

```
   <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding movieList}" Name="innerList">
      <ListBox.ItemTemplate >
         <DataTemplate >
            <TextBox Text="-------" TextChanged="TextBox_TextChanged_1"/>
         </DataTemplate>
       </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
   </ListBox>
```

EDIT:

Sorry, movie list was an observablecollection (of Movie) instead of being (of String)

How do I get the textbox to show the contents of its ancestor (the innerList) ?

Comment: Actually I'm not sure I understood your question correctly... what exactly are you trying to display in the TextBox?

Comment: contents of movieList. They work without using any item templates, but i need them to be editable

Comment: this is not precise enough... do you want to display all the movies in the same TextBox? Or do you want to show the title (or another property) of each movie in a different TextBox?

Comment: yes, each of the items of the list box (each movie) should show up as a separate text box

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to display the title of a movie in the TextBox, just use that:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Title}" TextChanged="TextBox_TextChanged_1"/>
```

(assuming the items in the list are objects with a `Title` property)

Comment: didn't work:( I tried movieList as well as innerList. Works without the itemTemplates, i just need them to be editable so i used textbox

Comment: Sorry, movie list was an observablecollection (of Movie)

Answer (score 1):

From [Binding Declarations Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752300.aspx)

> Optionally, a period (.) path can be used to bind to the current
>   source. For example, Text="{Binding}" is equivalent to Text="{Binding
>   Path=.}".

So following should do it.

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding}" TextChanged="TextBox_TextChanged_1"/>
```

Comment: they didn't work. I tried 
Text="{Binding}"
Text="{Binding Path=.}" and
Text="{Binding .}"